# Googlesheet Zon Zero Values Without Gap

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In GoogleSheet
Following is Column A & B with input values and i require in column C&B as shown in an image[image]. which formula i should put in cell c2 and cell d2 to have values as shown in image. plz help

Answer (score 0):

Try with the formula

`=Arrayformula(QUERY({To_Text(A:A)},"select Col1 where Col1 <> '0'"))`

`=Arrayformula(QUERY({To_Text(B:B)},"select Col1 where Col1 <> '0'"))`

Old answer below (not useful in this use case):

> *If you set all columns as plain text you can use this formula*
>
> *IN CELL C `=QUERY(A:A,"select A where A<>'0'")`*
>
> *IN CELL D `=QUERY(B:B,"select B where B<>'0'")`*

Comment: tried but it is showing an error like #N/A, column A & B have values but based on formula in them.

Comment: updated with a new formula, try this solution

Comment: @Juanhue another alternative (maybe better one ) can be the filter function
`=filter(A:A, A:A<>0)` into the C column and `=filter(B:B, B:B<>0)` into the D column

Comment: raising a loud thanks for you, it was very important for me to resolve it. soooo nice, may you be filled with happiness.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with the results being text and not numbers, you can use the following:

C: `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(A:A, "#")), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")`
D: `=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(B:B, "#")), "select Col1 where Col1 is not null")`

For more information about the `QUERY` function in Google Sheets, you can find the docs [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).